# BuiltInNUnitRunner.cs not found while debugging

Tags: visual-studio, nunit

I have a multi-project solution which is backed up by NUnit tests for every subproject. The unit tests are passing for other files. Strangely, for the new item added I am getting BuiltInNUnitRunner.cs     not found. Tried to restart the system, ensure the .cs file is available. However, VisualStudio 2017 will not pick up from the call stack frame.  The screenshot below for more detail call stack

[image]

Comment: Is BuiltInNUnitRunner.cs a file of yours?

Comment: Have you check if that file exists on that location?

Answer (score 1):

A little late to this party, but in my case I had a typo in a file path of a process that I was trying to open using Process.Start.  It was throwing the error described by @Varun Maggo.  I was able to figure this out because, in the Unit Testing Output window, the call stack shown in the error message pointed to the line in question.

So it is probable that the error you're seeing is masking the real issue.